# Comparing folder mtime with file mtime

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare the mtime of a folder with the mtime of a 7z file to decide if i need to run an update on the zipfile.

```
if (os.stat(os.path.join(path1,single_dir)).st_mtime > os.stat(os.path.join(path2,single_dir + suffix)).st_mtime):      
    cmd = ['E:/apps/7-Zip/7z.exe','u', os.path.join(path2,single_dir) + suffix, os.path.join(path1,single_dir),'-uq0']
    sp = subprocess.call(cmd)
```

But i noticed that this only seems to work if the folder structure changes, not if the file content within the folder is modified.

What would be a decent approach for such am operation ? Do i need to resort to recursive file comparison?

Ideally i would like to find a solution that would also work on windows as well as linux.

Comment: Are you in control of the process that will change the files?  Because, while the folder's mtime doesn't seem to update when existing files are changed, mtime *does* seem to update when new files are created in that directory.  Could you `touch .tickle; rm .tickle` whenever you update the files?  Or are you just monitoring a folder some out-of-your-control process manages?  Another thought, would finding the maximum mtime of the child files suffice?  That'd be easily done with a few extra lines of code.

Comment: The file changing process is out of my control - i need to find out if they have changed. Something like max mtime of the child files should be fine i guess - that's a good idea.